# Display product attribute value from array on product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to retrieve and display my product attribute value on product page:

```
$discounts = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_my_discounts' );
```

`_my_discount` is an array containing different discounts. Each discount contains different information (`min_qty`, `discount`, `type`, `is_flat` etc). When I use `echo var_dump($discounts);`
I get the following output (I have two discounts):

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) {
["58038e0802c2252b7f50a70d25a33ede"]=> array(7) { ["min_qty"]=> int(4) ["discount"]=> string(3) "100" ["type"]=> int(2) ["role"]=> string(3) "any" ["position"]=> string(1) "0" ["is_flat"]=> int(1) ["is_variations_sep"]=> int(0)
["007632f30006ccaac16982b779ec57ae"]=> array(7) { ["min_qty"]=> int(8) ["discount"]=> string(3) "293" ["type"]=> int(2) ["role"]=> string(3) "any" ["position"]=> string(1) "0" ["is_flat"]=> int(1) ["is_variations_sep"]=> int(0)
```

My question is, how do I retrieve the highest discount out of the array in `["discount"]` and display it on product page? For example the above product has two discounts $100 & $293. I want to retrieve the highest of the two and display it on my product page.

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
foreach ( $discounts as $highest_discount ) : 
$discount_value = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $highest_discount['discount'], array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
echo $discount_value;
endforeach;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to compare the discounts in your loop, to be able to see witch is the highest. I only see that you are echoing them all out atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write small function that finds which array element has the highest discount.

```
function find_highest_discount($discounts){
  $max_discount=0;
  foreach($discounts as $ds0){
      if ($ds0['discount']>$max_discount) $max_discount=$ds0['discount'];
  }
  return $max_discount;
}
```

Usage

```
$discounts = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_my_discounts' );
$highest_discount=find_highest_discount($discounts[0]);
```

Update: Similar function can be created to get the lowest number.

```
function find_lowest_discount($discounts){
  $min_discount=array_values($discounts)[0]['discount'];
  foreach($discounts as $ds0){
      if ($ds0['discount']<$min_discount) $min_discount=$ds0['discount'];
  }
  return $min_discount;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are passing correct argument here $highest_discount=find_highest_discount($discounts[0]). - [0] is important. If still no luck, add the latest state of code to your question, as an update

Comment: i have just tested my code on my localhost and it gave correct output (293)

Comment: i have updated my answer for your last request. check it pls.